# How to display a different value than used for calculation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The user inputs a percent value in the 0-100 range that they are used to as normal percentages.

But when these values are used for calculation they need to be in the `0-1` range, so divided by 100, so they can be used directly in calculations.

I use `Math.round(value * 100) / 10000` to divide by 100 so the number will be rounded to 2 digits.

One solution uses databinding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.percent = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).change(function () {
            DEBUG && log('Percent changed: ' + $(this).number() + ' saved as: ' + $(this).number() / 100);
            valueAccessor()(Math.round($(this).number({ round: false }) * 100) / 10000);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        DEBUG && log('Percent changed: ' + value + ' displayed as: ' + value * 100);
        $(element).val(Math.round(value * 10000) / 100);
    }
};
```

But this results in the values being displayed are times 100 of what the user puts in.

So it looks like the divide by 100 is not happening.

The `bindinghandler` is being applied through `databind="percent`: `Property".`

Another solution uses an extra extender:

```
obj.Property.extend({ AdvancedCalculation: null, Percent: null }); // Already tried flipping the order of these extenders.

ko.extenders.Percent = function (target) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            DEBUG && log('Value in model: ' + target());
            return Math.round(target() * 10000) / 100; // Show
        },
        write: function (value) {
            DEBUG && log('Save user input: ' + value);
            return Math.round(value * 100) / 10000; // To database
        }
    });

    return result;
}

ko.extenders.AdvancedCalculation = function (target) {
    target.subscribe(function (value) {
        DEBUG && log('Value in model ' + value);
        // calculate some other stuff.
    });

    return target;
};
```

But the advanced calculation stuff is not getting the divided by 100 value.

Also my controller, where the data is saved, is getting the value that the user inputs in the browser instead of the divided by 100 value.

Also the user should be able to use both , and . to indicate point numbers

(for example: `5.4% or 5,4%`).

This will be used to input intrest rates.

The two solutions where never both applied at the same time, so they can't have collided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you're trying to have two different values for the one property. And you don't seem to have a clear semantic way of distinguishing which one you actually expect to get.

Try doing stuff simple, so it works.

- have one property in percent,  which is persisted and
- sets the second property (read-only) in unit value.

Call these properties `RatePercent` and `RateUnitary` on somesuch.  You may also find it useful to have a `RateMultiplier` or somesuch, being 1.00 + RateUnitary.

Comment: Actually I think having another variable makes stuff more complicated. But it should make things better.

Comment: You need to be absolutely clearly able to distinguish which value/ scaling you're referring to -- therefore, in compiler & language terms, they are separate.  If you wanted to do an OO solution, you could have a 'PercentValue' class with both PercentValue and UnitaryValue properties.